# get full source of a file from a relative path on the client side in the context of an import statement in a vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

How do you do this?

I have a statement that looks like this:

```
import data from '/../server/data.json';
```

I want to see the full path of the resolved file.

I know that there's `resolve()` for node but thats backend I want to do it on front end

[How to get full path from relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096417/how-to-get-full-path-from-relative-path)

The problem with this answer is it's jquery - can you do it without?

[Converting Relative Paths to Absolute Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204955/converting-relative-paths-to-absolute-paths)

Not JS but java

[Javascript paths relative to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699606/javascript-paths-relative-to-file)

This is the closest, so I tried

```
import data from '/../server/data.json';

console.log(data.href)
```

This obviously doesn't work because it's not a valid attr.

My biggest issue here is trying to do this with an `import` statement. none of the attached answers discuss this.

Is this possible? Or am I in a black hole?

Comment: This doesn't make sense and won't work. Imports are for files that are local to frontend project. Their content is retrieved at the time when the app is built. Otherwise just fetch a file from some public location. Since it's .json and not .js, there won't be problems with this

Comment: except there was, and I was trying to debug it

Answer (score 1):

If using Vite, you can use the [`url` suffix on the `import` path](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url):

```js
                                         
import dataUrl from '../server/data.json?url'
```

If the file size is less than 4KB, it will be automatically inlined, so you'd see a data URL instead of a file path. To disable this inlining, set [`build.assetsInlineLimit`](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-assetsinlinelimit) to `0`:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    assetsInlineLimit: 0,
  },
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-get-url-of-imported-file?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)